# Drupal 7 Menu Parent module alternative

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am currently using the Node Collection module to handle parent child relationships on my site. This module creates a menu in the form [parent , child-1, child-2 ... child-n] is there a way for me to attach this menu to an item in the main menu in drupal 7?  And if so would this work with the Menu Firstchild modules?

Answer (score 0):

The menu system in drupal 7 isn't very good.

Instead of forcing node collection on the main menu i suggest you don't use the main menu block.

Use a node collection block, if exist, or create your own custom block using hook_block_info & hook_block_view.